# the following is a short script from TV i would like to convert to C#

Tags: algorithm, build, algorithmic-trading

.

```
strategy("DailyCandleCross", shorttitle="DCC", overlay=true, calc_on_order_fills= true, calc_on_every_tick=true, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=75, pyramiding=0)
    A=security(tickerid, 'D', close)
    B=security(tickerid, 'D', close[1])
    C=A>B
if(C)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if(not C)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
```

I'm not a computer nerd, algorithms are a new thing for me